# Repeating sequence based on another value

Tags: r, dplyr, sequence

I'm dealing with a data structure set up like so:

**Data**

```
structure(list(ID = c(1147L, 1147L, 1147L, 1147L, 1147L, 1147L, 
1147L, 1147L, 1147L, 1147L, 1147L, 1147L, 4085L, 4085L, 4085L, 
4085L, 4085L, 4085L, 4085L), year = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), term = c(1L, 
3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 
5L, 1L), reportedFY = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), minFY = c(2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

```
ID  year    term    reportedFY  minFY
1147    1   1   NA  2016
1147    1   3   NA  2016
1147    1   5   NA  2016
1147    2   1   NA  2016
1147    2   3   NA  2016
1147    2   5   NA  2016
1147    3   1   NA  2016
1147    3   3   NA  2016
1147    3   5   NA  2016
1147    4   1   NA  2016
1147    4   3   NA  2016
1147    4   5   NA  2016
4085    1   1   NA  2019
4085    1   3   NA  2019
4085    1   5   NA  2019
4085    2   1   NA  2019
4085    2   3   NA  2019
4085    2   5   NA  2019
4085    3   1   NA  2019
```

Each ID (of which there are around ~9000, repeat 12 times each, with each year repeating 3 times. What I'm trying to do is repeat a sequence for each ID based on the minFY. So ID 1147 would have a sequence of 2016,2017,2018,2019 where each year is repeated 3 times. Whereas 4085 would have a sequence 2019,2020,2021,2022 that repeat 3 times each.

I've been trying to use something along the lines of this, which obviously isn't working:

```
prog_structure2$reportedFY <- rep(c(minFY, minFY+1, minFY+2, minFY+3), time=9306, each=3)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You could try ```expand.grid(ID = c(1147, 4085), year = 1:3, term = c(1, 3, 5), reportedFY = NA, minFY = 0)``` (where you replace ID with the 9306 IDs), then set reportedFY to year and add the appropriate amount of years per ID.

Comment: Maybe try: `with(prog_structure2, ave(minFY, ID, FUN=function(x) seq(x[1], length.out=4)))`

Comment: or `i <- seq(1, by=12, length.out=ceiling(nrow(prog_structure2)/12)); c(apply(sapply(prog_structure2$minFY[i], seq, length.out=4), 2, rep, 3))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base R

```
df$reportedFY <- ave(df$minFY, df$ID, FUN = function(x) rep(min(x) + 0:3, each = 3))

     ID year term reportedFY minFY
1  1147    1    1       2016  2016
2  1147    1    3       2016  2016
3  1147    1    5       2016  2016
4  1147    2    1       2017  2016
5  1147    2    3       2017  2016
6  1147    2    5       2017  2016
7  1147    3    1       2018  2016
8  1147    3    3       2018  2016
9  1147    3    5       2018  2016
10 1147    4    1       2019  2016
11 1147    4    3       2019  2016
12 1147    4    5       2019  2016
13 4085    1    1       2019  2019
14 4085    1    3       2019  2019
15 4085    1    5       2019  2019
16 4085    2    1       2020  2019
17 4085    2    3       2020  2019
18 4085    2    5       2020  2019
19 4085    3    1       2021  2019
```

Answer (score 0):

This should works for you :

```
library(dplyr)
d <- data.frame('ID' = c(rep(1147, 12), rep(4085,12)), 
'year' =  rep(rep(1:4,each=3),2), 
'term' = rep(c(1,3,5),8),
'reportedFY' = NA, 
'minFY' = c(rep(2016, 12), rep(2019,12)))
 
 d <- d %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(reportedFY = rep(seq(first(minFY),(first(minFY)+3)),each = 3))
```

Comment: I'm getting a similar error as above:```Error in seq.default(first(minFY), (first(minFY) + 3)) : 
  'from' must be of length 1```

Comment: May you show exactly what you type in R ? you should not get any error. This solution is exactly the same given a couples minutes before above. what do you obtain if you type `seq.default(first(d$minFY), (first(d$minFY) + 3))`